# Resampling grouped data to obtain daily average data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas and I'm having some problems when I try to obtain daily average from data file.

So, my data is structured as follows:

```
                      DATA  ESTACION
DATETIME                           
2020-01-15 00:00:00   175        47
2020-01-15 01:00:00   152        47
2020-01-15 02:00:00   180        47
2020-01-15 03:00:00   132        47
2020-01-15 04:00:00   115        47
...                   ...       ...
2020-03-13 19:00:00    38        16
2020-03-13 20:00:00    53        16
2020-03-13 21:00:00    73        16
2020-03-13 22:00:00    28        16
2020-03-13 23:00:00    22        16
```

These are air pollution results gathered by 24 stations. Each station receives hourly information as you can see.

I'm trying to get daily average data by station. So this is what I do:

I group all info by station

```
grouped = data.groupby(['ESTACION'])
```

Then I get daily average resampling the grouped data

```
resampled = grouped.resample('D').mean()
```

And this is what I've obtained:

```
                            DATA  ESTACION
ESTACION DATETIME                        
4        2020-01-02   18.250000       4.0
         2020-01-03         NaN       NaN
         2020-01-04         NaN       NaN
         2020-01-05         NaN       NaN
         2020-01-06         NaN       NaN
...                         ...       ...
60       2020-11-29         NaN       NaN
         2020-11-30         NaN       NaN
         2020-12-01         NaN       NaN
         2020-12-02  118.666667      60.0
         2020-12-03   80.833333      60.0
```

I don't really know whats going on cause I've only got data for 2020-01-15 - 2020-03-13 and it shows me info from other timestamps and NaN results.

If you need anything else to reproduce this case let me know.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: If you put a minimalistic working version of your code it makes it easier for people to test it and help you.

Comment: Did you try `grouped = data.groupby(['ESTACION']).mean()`?

Comment: Thanks @Raf. But I'm looking for daily average for each station, not the total average for each station.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output is expected, because `resample` always create consecutive `DatetimeIndex`.

So is possible remove missing rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
resampled = grouped.resample('D').mean().dropna()
```

Another solution is use [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
data.groupby(['ESTACION', data['DATETIME'].dt.date]).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I tried both solutions but I don't uderstand why the output changes DATETIME format. I started with yyyy:mm:dd and then the output changes to yyyy:dd:mm

Comment: @guaremate - What is your code for convert column to datetime?

Comment: I'm using pandas.to_datetime(data.DATETIME)

Comment: @guaremate - Maybe `pandas.to_datetime(data.DATETIME, dayfirst=True)` working?